# How to GROUPING SETS as operator/method on Dataset?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

Is there no function level grouping_sets support in spark scala?

I have no idea this patch applied to master
https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/5080

I want to do this kind of query by scala dataframe api.

```
GROUP BY expression list GROUPING SETS(expression list2)
```

`cube` and `rollup` [functions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) are available in Dataset API, but can't find grouping sets. Why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I want to do this kind of query by scala dataframe api.

**tl;dr** Up to Spark 2.1.0 it is not possible. There are currently no plans to add such an operator to Dataset API.

Spark SQL supports the following so-called **multi-dimensional aggregate operators**:

- `rollup` operator
- `cube` operator
- `GROUPING SETS` clause (only in SQL mode)
- `grouping()` and `grouping_id()` functions

**NOTE:** `GROUPING SETS` is only available in SQL mode. There is no support in Dataset API.

### GROUPING SETS

```scala
val sales = Seq(
  ("Warsaw", 2016, 100),
  ("Warsaw", 2017, 200),
  ("Boston", 2015, 50),
  ("Boston", 2016, 150),
  ("Toronto", 2017, 50)
).toDF("city", "year", "amount")
sales.createOrReplaceTempView("sales")

// equivalent to rollup("city", "year")
val q = sql("""
  SELECT city, year, sum(amount) as amount
  FROM sales
  GROUP BY city, year
  GROUPING SETS ((city, year), (city), ())
  ORDER BY city DESC NULLS LAST, year ASC NULLS LAST
  """)

scala> q.show
+-------+----+------+
|   city|year|amount|
+-------+----+------+
| Warsaw|2016|   100|
| Warsaw|2017|   200|
| Warsaw|null|   300|
|Toronto|2017|    50|
|Toronto|null|    50|
| Boston|2015|    50|
| Boston|2016|   150|
| Boston|null|   200|
|   null|null|   550|  <-- grand total across all cities and years
+-------+----+------+
```

```
// equivalent to cube("city", "year")
// note the additional (year) grouping set
val q = sql("""
  SELECT city, year, sum(amount) as amount
  FROM sales
  GROUP BY city, year
  GROUPING SETS ((city, year), (city), (year), ())
  ORDER BY city DESC NULLS LAST, year ASC NULLS LAST
  """)

scala> q.show
+-------+----+------+
|   city|year|amount|
+-------+----+------+
| Warsaw|2016|   100|
| Warsaw|2017|   200|
| Warsaw|null|   300|
|Toronto|2017|    50|
|Toronto|null|    50|
| Boston|2015|    50|
| Boston|2016|   150|
| Boston|null|   200|
|   null|2015|    50|  <-- total across all cities in 2015
|   null|2016|   250|  <-- total across all cities in 2016
|   null|2017|   250|  <-- total across all cities in 2017
|   null|null|   550|
+-------+----+------+
```

---

If a value in a column of resulting table is `null`, it may not necessarily mean that the column was aggregated on that row. If that column has `null`s in the original table, `null` value in the aggregations table may represent just a `null` value from the original table. Use [grouping](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.grouping.html#pyspark.sql.functions.grouping) function to check if the column was aggregated on the specific row or not.

Comment: how to query reports like I want to fectch total across city 2015. Do I need to put all other column as null. e.g 
select amount from table where year=2015 and city is null  and every other column is null

Comment: @PushpendraJaiswal That'd be my suggestion exactly.

Comment: If a value in a column of resulting table is null, it may not necessarily mean that the column was aggregated on that row. If that column has nulls in the original table, null value in the aggregations table may represent just a null value from the original table. You can check if the column was aggregated on the specific row by using [grouping](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.grouping.html#pyspark.sql.functions.grouping) function.

Answer (score 0):

Spark supports `GROUPING SETS`. You can find corresponding tests here:

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/5b7d403c1819c32a6a5b87d470f8de1a8ad7a987/sql/core/src/test/resources/sql-tests/inputs/group-analytics.sql#L25-L28

Comment: but how about dataframe function api. I can not find it.

Comment: There isn't. It is available only in SQL.