# How to group by rollup on only some columns in Apache Spark SQL?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I'm using the the SQL API for Spark 3.0 in a Databricks 7.0 runtime cluster. I know that I can do the following:

```
select
  coalesce(a, "All A") as colA,
  coalesce(b, "All B") as colB,
  sum(c) as sumC
from
  myTable
group by rollup (
  colA,
  colB
)
order by
  colA asc,
  colB asc
```

I'd then expect an output like:

```
+-------+-------+------+
| colA  | colB  | sumC |
+-------+-------+------+
| All A | All B |  300 |
| a1    | All B |  100 |
| a1    | b1    |  30  |
| a1    | b2    |  70  |
| a2    | All B |  200 |
| a2    | b1    |  50  |
| a2    | b2    |  150 |
+-------+-------+------+
```

However, I'm trying to write a query where only column b needs to be rolled up. I've written something like:

```
select
  a as colA,
  coalesce(b, "All B") as colB,
  sum(c) as sumC
from
  myTable
group by 
  a,
  rollup (b)
order by
  colA asc,
  colB asc
```

And I'd expect an output like:

```
+-------+-------+------+
| colA  | colB  | sumC |
+-------+-------+------+
| a1    | All B |  100 |
| a1    | b1    |  30  |
| a1    | b2    |  70  |
| a2    | All B |  200 |
| a2    | b1    |  50  |
| a2    | b2    |  150 |
+-------+-------+------+
```

I know this sort of operation is supported in at least some SQL APIs, but I get `Error in SQL statement: UnsupportedOperationException` when trying to run the above query. Does anyone know whether this behavior is simply as-of-yet unsupported in Spark 3.0 or if I just have the syntax wrong? The [docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#rollup) aren't helpful on the subject.

I know that I can accomplish this with `union all`, but I'd prefer to avoid that route, if only for the sake of elegance and brevity.

Thanks in advance, and please let me know if I can clarify anything.

Comment: You may be able to do it with `GROUPING SETS` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40923680/how-to-grouping-sets-as-operator-method-on-dataset. Available in SQL only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this `GROUPING SETS` option:

```
%sql
SELECT 
  COALESCE( a, 'all a' ) a, 
  COALESCE( b, 'all b' ) b, 
  SUM(c) c
FROM myTable
GROUP BY a, b
GROUPING SETS ( ( a , b ), a )
ORDER BY a, b
```

My results (with updated numbers):

[image: My results]

Comment: I believe `GROUPING SETS` is indeed what I need here. Thank you very much. The syntax you've provided doesn't _quite_ achieve the desired output (it looks like you're doing something semantically equivalent to `GROUP BY ROLLUP`). I'll experiment later this week when I have time again, and once I have the right syntax, I'll follow up. From there, if you update your answer to match, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thanks Keith - I was guessing a bit as your numbers don’t quite add up but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: Sorry about that—the numbers were just placeholders. I'll update the question to make them clearer.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer—your output is what I'm looking for, but I don't understand why. I guess I don't yet understand what `GROUPING SETS` is doing under the hood well enough. The actual query I'm working on has five columns in the `GROUP BY`, but only the fourth column needs the additional aggregation, so I'm trying to figure out how to apply the abstracted version in this question to the actual query.

Comment: How are you getting on?  `GROUPING SETS` is standard ANSI SQL so you should be able to read about it and how it works.  The way I think of it is, grouping sets can add extra summary rows to your result and you control what those rows are.  Two brackets () is shorthand for "summarise everything"; there's some other notes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25274879/when-to-use-grouping-sets-cube-and-rollup).

Comment: I've had the opportunity to use `GROUPING SETS` in a few other contexts now, and it's beginning to make a lot more sense with practice. Thank you again for pointing me in the right direction!